# Clearing activity stack. First run activities

Tags: java, android

I've got an application that launches an introduction flow on first run like this:

**ON FIRST RUN**

**A: Intro text**

**B: Terms and conditions**

**C: Choose language**

After all these steps have been completed, the application sets a first_run attribute to false and launches activity **D**.

Now, what I want to do is either clear the activity stack so that when the user presses the back button it goes back to the Home screen rather than activity **C** and then when the application launches again it goes straight to activity **D**.

Any ideas on how I would go about doing this?

**EDIT**

I'm aware that calling finish() on each activity removes it from the stack. But my real problem is that if the user wants to go back from **B** to **A** it won't work if I've already called finish() on **A**. Sorry for not specifying this earlier.

Comment: in my oppenion, Clear the stack

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is gonna work for sure, apologies for the last post.
I realised it later that it wont work.

In Activity A, B and C use:

```
BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("ActivityA", "finishing A");
        finish();
    }
};

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
    super.onDestroy();
} // This is mandatory to unregister the receiver, else error occur
```

In onCreate of these activities, add:

```
IntentFilter myFilter = new IntentFilter("finish_my_activities");
registerReceiver(myReceiver, myFilter);
```

In activity D, where you wanna finish all this:

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent("finish_my_activities"));
//Where ever you wanna finish those activities
```

Comment: Also, make the first_run variable to be false anly once the user has successfully launched the activity "C".

Comment: Ah, yes that would work in a way. But let's say if I'm a **B** and want to go back to **A**? That won't work if I call finish() on **A**, right? That's why I want to clear the whole stack from **A** to **C** if that's at all possible. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Tried it but it only removes **C** from the stack once I launch **D**. **A** and **B** are still intact. So, when I launch **D** and press the back button I end up in **B**.

Comment: I have tested the code first and it fits all the requirements you asked.

Comment: Great stuff! Worked like a charm. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

well use SharedPreferences to save your first_reun attribute and check its value on the OnCreate of activities (A, B and c).

And then in your manifest add (android:noHistory="true") to the (D) Activity.