# Clear history stack after a period of time?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Is there an easy way to have the history stack cleared after a period of time?

I need to return to the log in screen either 1) after a period of time, or 2) after certain session variables no longer exist. I'm not sure how I can achieve this.

Comment: Just go for the BroadcastListener approach like here : <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8801957/clearing-activity-stack-first-run-activities/8802204#8802204>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to assume that "session variables" -- which neither Java nor Android have -- are really static data members. In that case:

Step #1: Have one of the "session variables" be the time of last login.

Step #2: In `onResume()` of each activity, check the last-login "session variable" to see if it is `null` or is too old -- in which case, you call `startActivity()` to launch your log-in screen.

Step #3: There is no Step #3.